How to add subfolders and add xml files under layout folder in "Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1"?
I have tried some solutions like -

Created "layouts" directory under "layout" folder and refractor and move the xml files but then in the layout folder did not see any subfolder or files, sync with gradle file, restart the IDE.
Created res.srcDirs in the build.gradle file.
But these solutions does not work.

When I created folder by using res.srcDirs or by manually create folder under the layout folder, it is showing in android studio after select file type "Packages" but selecting type "Android" it is not showing any subfolder.

Do you get any errors?  Are you looking at all file types (*).  You may not see all the files if you have any filter turned on.  You are not getting any errors so the files are probably being moved or you are not finding the source file.
